# How to secure blob storage access key in Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-storage, azure-keyvault

We would like to protect the Azure Blob Storage access key in key vault. Which version of https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-azure has support for such a capability, since the current support is not that secure.

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-azure/index.html

Usage of Azure Blob Storage requires configuration of credentials. Typically this is set in core-site.xml. The configuration property name is of the form fs.azure.account.key..blob.core.windows.net and the value is the access key. The access key is a secret that protects access to your storage account. Do not share the access key (or the core-site.xml file) with an untrusted party.

```
<property>
  <name>fs.azure.account.key.youraccount.blob.core.windows.net</name>
  <value>YOUR ACCESS KEY</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no support for this to my knowledge. But you can implement this in the given decrypt script in core-site.xml by connecting to KeyVault for decryption/or retrieval of the key.

```
<property>
  <name>fs.azure.shellkeyprovider.script</name>
  <value>/usr/lib/hdinsight-common/scripts/KeyVaultdecrypt.sh</value>
</property>
```